# How do cantrol URL slash after main domain vis .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**How do cantrol URL slash after main domain  vis .htaccess**
**For example **
now my site load like that

```
www.mysite.com/watch/9jkjndsa9323/
```

now i want is that possible do something only work 2 slash after main domain like 
after main domain only word 2 slash

```
 www.mysite.com/watch/9jkjndsa9323/
```

a user type

```
www.mysite.com/watch/9jkjndsa9323/sadk/asd/sad/asd/sad/sad/as/d
```

but server only show this page to it

```
 www.mysite.com/watch/9jkjndsa9323/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the htaccess file in your document root (preferably before any other mod_rewrite rules)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/.+/ /$1/$2/ [L,R]
```